# How to calculate SLA Availability

Tags: high-availability

Imagine that we have an API service with 99,9% of Availability.

So this API can be down just `1m 26.4s` daily.

So how do I measure if an API is down? IMO, i need a 
sampling rate, in the SLA contract too?

Does anyone can provide me an example?

Comment: "So how do I measure if an API is down?"  You probably need to write a custom check for the monitoring software of your choice.

Comment: Yep! But what is the strategy to measure the down time? Do I call the api 5minutes rate / 90 seconds? And when its down I continue to retry until it goes up?

Answer (score 1):

You need to monitor it.

At first, you need to say how is defined downtime for your api. Is it defined as client cannot connect, is it defined as no methods is working, is it defined as at least one method is not working?

Next step is write custom monitoring script or setup common monitoring solution (depends on step 1) and let this monitor your api.

Sample rate depends on your resources, but more often is better. I have multiple checks in range of 10s/check to 2min/check.

Of course you should monitor your api from different networks just to eliminate problem with one network or with one probe. So you will have lets say 3 VM across the Internet with monitoring script, this VMs will periodically check your API and report status to something, what will measure your SLA, alert you in case of outage and so on.

See: newrelic, pagerduty, thousandeyes, zabbix, nagios